# How can I insert text into Flexible or Expanded widget - flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design

So, I'm trying to create something like a login page in flutter. I'm wondering how I can achieve something like on the picture below:

[image: The design that I'm trying to copy]

So, that's basically a text inside container? But how can I do that using Flexible widget or Expanded widget. Because I'm trying to create a responsive layout that will fit for every screen, so I read that using Flex widget and then Expanded and Flexible widgets are a key to reach that. While I know how to create such a button using Container and experimenting with size of the container using MediaQuery, but I totally have no idea how to insert any text into container which is in Flexible widget. Does anyone have any idea?

I'm just wondering how to create such a button using only responsive elements? - I mean without using specified width and height (so only using flex parameter?)

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your Container widget without specifying the width in an Expanded widget. Know that you should have a Row (or a Column, depends) as the parent of the Expanded widget.

For example, having this code below gives you this output:

[image: Expanded Button]

```
Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: InkWell(
                  onDoubleTap: () => viewModel.signOut(),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.teal,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Logout (testing)',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Now tell me - I wrote like few times that I wanna achieve a responsive design. Firstly, the text won't scale with the container. On a bigger screen container will look more like a square rather than a square with a circular border-radius. I totally understand how to create such a design. I just don't know how to insert centered text inside a container, so it won't change the size of the container using RESPONSIVE DESIGN, without mediaquery, i don't know whether is it even possible.